# Find longest sequences with sufficient average score

Tags: algorithm

I have a long list of scores between 0 and 1. How do I efficiently find all contiguous sublists longer than x elements such that the average score in each sublist is not less than y?

E.g., how do I find all contiguous sublists longer than 300 elements such that the average score of these sublists is not less than 0.8?

I'm mainly interested in the LONGEST sublists that fulfill these criteria, not actually all sublists. So I'm looking for all longest sublists.

Comment: I can think of O(N^2) which doesn't sound like a good one.

Comment: do you mean a continuous sublist? so `(1, 3)` is not a sublist of `(1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: exactly, [1,3] is not a sublist of [1,2,3]. I'll clarify that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Let's say that all elements of the sublist from 1000 to 1999 are > 0.8: then you're saying that you want to report all 701 sublists 1000..1299, 1000..1300, 1000..1301, etc.; then all 700 sublists 1001..1300, 1001..1301, etc. -- roughly 700*700 sublists in all.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Hey, another clarification: the longest sublists would be sufficient

Comment: Thats become another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the *longest* such substrings, this can be solved in **O(n log n) time** by transforming the problem slightly and then binary-searching over maximum solution lengths.

Let the input list of scores be x[1], ..., x[n].  Let's transform this list by subtracting y from each element, to form the list z[1], ..., z[n], whose elements may be positive or negative.  Notice that any sublist x[i .. j] has average score at least y if and only if the *sum* of elements in the corresponding sublist in z (i.e., z[i] + z[i+1] +  ... + z[j]) is at least 0.  So, if we had a way to compute the *maximum* sum T of any sublist in z[] efficiently (spoiler: we do), this would, as a side effect, tell us if there is *any* sublist in x[] that has average score at least y: if T >= 0 then there is at least 1 such sublist, while if T < 0 then there is *no* sublist in x[] (not even a single-element sublist) that has average score at least y.  But this doesn't yet give us all the information we need to answer your original question, since nothing forces the maximum-sum sublist in z to have maximum *length*: it could well be that a longer sublist exists that has lower overall average, while still having average at least y.

This can be addressed by generalising the problem of finding the sublist with maximum sum: instead of asking for a sublist with maximum sum overall, we will now ask for a sublist having maximum sum *among all sublists having length at least some given k*.  I'll now describe an algorithm that, given a list of numbers z[1], ..., z[n], each of which can be positive or negative, and any positive integer k, will compute the maximum sum of any sublist of z[] having length *at least* k, as well as the location of a particular sublist that achieves this sum, and has longest possible length among all sublists having this sum.  It's a slight generalisation of [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm).

```
FindMaxSumLongerThan(z[], k):
    v = 0                 # Sum of the rightmost k numbers in the current sublist
    For i from 1 to k:
        v = v + z[i]

    best = v
    bestStart = 1
    bestEnd = k

    # Now for each i, with k+1 <= i <= n, find the biggest sum ending at position i.
    tail = -1          # Will contain the maximum sum among all lists ending at i-k
    tailLen = 0        # The length of the longest list having the above sum
    For i from k+1 to n:
        If tail >= 0:
            tail = tail + z[i-k]
            tailLen = tailLen + 1
        Else:
            tail = z[i-k]
            tailLen = 1

        If tail >= 0:
            nonnegTail = tail
            nonnegTailLen = tailLen
        Else:
            nonnegTail = 0
            nonnegTailLen = 0

        v = v + z[i] - z[i-k]    # Slide the window right 1 position
        If v + nonnegTail > best:
            best = v + nonnegTail
            bestStart = i - k - nonnegTailLen + 1
            bestEnd = i
```

The above algorithm takes O(n) time and O(1) space, returning the maximum sum in `best` and the beginning and ending positions of some sublist that achieves that sum in `bestStart` and `bestEnd`, respectively.

How is the above useful?  For a given input list x[], suppose we first transform x[] into z[] by subtracting y from each element as described above; this will be the z[] passed into every call to `FindMaxSumLongerThan()`.  We can view the value of `best` that results from calling the function with z[] and a given minimum sublist length k as a mathematical function of k: best(k).  Since `FindMaxSumLongerThan()` finds the maximum sum of any sublist of z[] having length *at least* k, best(k) is a nonincreasing function of k.  (Say we set k=5 and found that the maximum sum of any sublist is 42; then we are guaranteed to find a total of at least 42 if we try again with k=4 or k=3.)  That means **we can binary search on k** to find the largest k such that best(k) >= 0: that k will then be the *longest* sublist of x[] that has average value at least y.  The resulting `bestStart` and `bestEnd` will identify a particular sublist having this property; it's easy to modify the algorithm to find all (at most n -- one per rightmost position) of these sublists without increasing the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I think that general solution is always `O(N^2)`. I will demonstrate a code in Python and some optimizations you can implement to increase the performance by several orders of magnitude.

Let's generate some data:

```py
from random import random
scores_list = [random() for i in range(10000)]
scores_len = len(scores_list)
```

Let's say these are our target values:

```py
# Your average
avg = 0.55
# Your min lenght
min_len = 10
```

Here is a naive brute force solution

```py
res = []
for i in range(scores_len - min_len):
  for j in range(i+min_len, scores_len):
    l = scores_list[i:j]
    if sum(l) / (j - i) >= avg:
      res.append(l)
```

That will run very slowly because it has to perform `10000^2` (`10^8`) operations.

Here is how we can do it better. It is still quadratic but there is some tricks wich allows it to perform much much faster:

```py
res = []
i = 0
while i < scores_len - min_len:
  j = i + min_len
  di = scores_len
  dj = 0
  current_sum = sum(scores_list[i:j])
  while j < scores_len:
    current_sum += sum(scores_list[j-dj:j])
    current_avg = current_sum/(j - i)
    if current_avg >= avg:
      res.append(scores_list[i:j])
      dj = 1
      di = 1
    else:
      dj = max(1, int((avg * (j - i) - current_sum)/(1 - avg)))
      di = min(di, max(1, int(((j-i) * avg - current_sum)/avg)))
    j += dj
  i += di
```

For uniform distribution (which we have here) and for given target values it will perform only less than `10^6` operations (`~7 * 10^5`) and this is by two orders of magnitude less than brute force solution.

So basically if you have a few target sublists it will perform very good. And if you have a lot of them this algorithm will be about the same as a brute force one.